# "Unable to load settings." when changing the Wii U form Composite to HDMI

Tags: wii-u

I have this problem when I try to change my Wii U from Composite to HDMI. I get:

> Unable to load settings.
>
> Turn the console off, and then try again.

I have turned the console off and tried again, but I still get the same message.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just to be sure: is your Wii U connected to a screen over HDMI?

Comment: Well, yes. That is a bit obvious. I tried a Samsung TV (HDMI) and a Compaq Monitor (HDMI to DVI). Both work with a PC and a PS4, so it not a problem with the screens or cables.